# Mingw32-make install error while installing OpenCV-4.3 windows

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, mingw-w64, cmake-gui

Binaries are built using cmake with mingw makefiles as a generator, windows 10 x64, the installation made using following guide [Link](https://medium.com/csmadeeasy/opencv-c-installation-on-windows-with-mingw-c0fc1499f39)

```
[ 42%] Building RC object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/vs_version.rc.obj
>    gcc: error: long: No such file or directory
>     C:\PROGRA~1\MINGW-~1\X86_64~1.0- 
>     P\mingw64\bin\windres.exe: preprocessing failed.
>     mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules\core\CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir\build.make:1495:
> modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/vs_version.rc.obj] Error 1
>     mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1853: modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
>     mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:182: all] Error 2
```

Comment: `gcc: error: long: No such file or directory`  you will have to debug that. I expect more errors above this line of output.

Comment: The guide looks reasonable.

Comment: Its in another drive , mingw is in C drive

Comment: did you check this https://answers.opencv.org/question/228737/gcc-error-long-no-such-file-or-directory/?